# PHP/Laravel casting and rounding string to int

Tags: php, laravel, web

I'm sending a POST request to my Laravel controller with a STRING variable "tweetId" (looks like this "1143910903294898176").
The problem is that the controller is casting the variable to an int and rounding the number (it ends up like this 1143910903294898200). I'm not sure if its a PHP or a Laravel issue.
The weird thing is that if i do dd($request), the variable is still the original string, but if i do $request->tweet_id then i get the rounded int.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    return $request->input('tweet_id');
}
```

Comment: I've never heard of php doing this. Definitely sounds like something you're doing in your form or POST variable validation.

Comment: My js function is sending a string correctly. The Controller is also receiving it just fine. Now i'm thinking the issue may be in the response.

Comment: You could cast this request property to a string like this:
`(string) $request->tweet_id`

Comment: perhaps there is a middleware change these attributes